# Полностью очистить буфер терминала linux СИ

Tags: linux, c, gcc, консоль, ascii

необходимо полностью очистить буфер консоли (не сдвинуть кучей \n или еще чем нибудь на подобии этоого , а именно очистить)
Найти в гугле как это сделать не удалось.
без использования сторонних библиотек

Comment: буфер ввода или вывода? пользовательский или ядра? ввода или вывода? уточни примером кода, если не знаешь точно...

Answer (score 2):

Судя по [Clearing terminal in Linux with C++ code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4062051), этого можно достичь с помощью так называемых ANSI escape codes:

```
std::cout << "\033[2J\033[1;1H";
```

`\033[2J` очищает экран, а `\033[1;1H` перемещает курсор в верхний-левый угол экрана.

Comment: да, я сначала тоже наткнулся на это, printf("\033[2J\033[1;1H"); но у меня почему то коснтрукция подобного рода не работает. Просто напросто не стирает то что было напечатано ранее и плюс к этому появляются непонятные проблемы с выводом

Comment: @владимирзайцев, в большинстве эмуляторов это работает. Вы чем пользуетесь?

Comment: да вот тем что идет по умолчанию в убунте

Comment: Кажется тут не хватает экранирования. `"\\033"` чтобы на выход записалось `\033`

Comment: @VTT Вроде оно все-таки не нужно. `033`-ий символ в ASCII это `ESC`, что вполне соответствует названию "escape codes". Да и было бы странно, если терминалом можно было бы управлять одними только печатными символами.

Comment: `"\033"` выведет 3 символа - `<ascii_null>33`, а не четыре `\033`, как раз таки все символы в выводе должны быть печатными

Comment: @VTT Он один символ выведет. Также, как, например, `"\077"` выведет `?`.

Comment: я имею ввиду С код, `\0` в начале - это окончание строки и до эмулятора терминала вообще ничего не дойдет

Comment: Нет нет, `\0` - это частный случай записи `\0[цифра][цифра]` (может быть разное количество цифр), которая создает произвольные символы по их восьмеричному ASCII-коду. http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/16cbed47ac00cdc2

Comment: Вроде где-то что-то включить надо, чтобы это работало?

Answer (score 1):

```
$ man system
```

Самый простой вариант для Linux:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(const char *command) 
{
     system("clear");

     return 0;
}
```